# How to read and parse the values from text file as per the environments in power shell?

Tags: powershell

I am new in powershell and working on script where I have txt file which is in below format

file name abc.txt

```
ABC=WINDOW01
ABC_NCD_PP

CDE=WINDOW02
CDE_NN_01

EFG=WINDO03
DD_PP_01
```

Below I am trying with my script

```
function Show-Menu
{
    param (
        [string]$Title = 'My Menu'
    )
    Clear-Host
    Write-Host "================ $Title ================"
    Write-Host "1: Press '1' to list all the Window Boxes"
    Write-Host "Q: Press 'Q' to quit."
}

function Vm-List 
{
    Write-Output "Below are the window boxes"
    $serverlist = @(get-content  -Path "k:\abc.txt")
    $counter = 0
    foreach ($server in $serverlist)
    {
      $counter++
    write-host ""$counter": Press '"$counter"' to select : $server"
    }

}

do
{
     Show-Menu
     $input = Read-Host "Please make a selection"
     switch ($input)
     {
           '1' {
                Vm-List

           } 'q' {
                return
           }
     }
     pause
}
until ($input -eq 'q')
```

I want when user Press 1 it should display all window box in below format

```
1: Press '1' to select ABC window box WINDOW01
2: Press '2' to select CDE window box WINDOW02
3: Press '3' to select EFG window box WINDOW03
Q: Press 'q' to quit
Please make a selection:
```

Once I select any option from above then it should display the value according to that box.for e.g if I select 1 then it should show(these value could be more)

```
List of all envs:
1: Press '1' to select ABC_NCD_PP
R: Press 'r' to return
Q: Press 'q' to quit
Please make a selection:
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu are really over complicating this. effort. Also, you've got more than one question/problem case here, and being new you are trying to build an MDI console app. I'd say that is a bit much for a beginner.

The reason you are not getting what you are after is:

1. You are not parsing that text file at all to get the text you want
   to display as you show
2. You really do not have MDI approach configured for that second menu
   at all.

Being new to something is just, fine, but not, at minimum, going to get some ramp-up training prior to trying to use it,  is not. Especially with the tons of free videos, tutorials, blogs, sample code, reference books, etc., all over the web. Use the help files built-into the system.

```
# All Help topics and locations
Get-Help about_*
Get-Help about_Functions

Get-Help about* | Select Name, Synopsis

Get-Help about* | 
Select-Object -Property Name, Synopsis |
Out-GridView -Title 'Select Topic' -OutputMode Multiple |
ForEach-Object { Get-Help -Name $_.Name -ShowWindow }

explorer "$pshome\$($Host.CurrentCulture.Name)"

# Get parameters, examples, full and Online help for a cmdlet or function

# Get a list of all functions
Get-Command -CommandType Function | 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available functions'

# Get a list of all commandlets
Get-Command -CommandType Cmdlet | 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available cmdlets'

# Get a list of all functions for the specified name
Get-Command -Name '*VM*' -CommandType Function | 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available named functions'

# Get a list of all commandlets for the specified name
Get-Command -Name '*VM**'  -CommandType Cmdlet | 
Out-GridView -PassThru -Title 'Available named cmdlet'

# get function / cmdlet details
Get-Command -Name Get-VM -Syntax
(Get-Command -Name Get-VM).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Get-VM -Full
Get-help -Name Get-VM -Online
Get-help -Name Get-VM -Examples

Get-Command -Name Out-GridView -Syntax
(Get-Command -Name Out-GridView ).Parameters.Keys
Get-help -Name Out-GridView -Full
Get-help -Name Out-GridView -Online
Get-help -Name Out-GridView -Examples
```

So, jump on Youtube, and search for an use the training there

> ['beginning Powershell'](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=beginning%20powershell)

Your real question here is...

> ['how to write a console menu in PowerShell'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27how%20to%20write%20a%20console%20menu%20in%20PowerShell%27&form=ANSPH1&refig=17959e151d334a80bad5dcce65e98c4c&sp=-1&pq=%27how%20to%20write%20a%20console%20menu%20in%20powershell%27&sc=0-43&qs=n&sk=&cvid=17959e151d334a80bad5dcce65e98c4c)

...and doing that string search would return you a very long list of samples to use.

For Example:

> [Building a PowerShell Console Menu Revisited, Part 1](https://www.petri.com/building-a-powershell-console-menu-revisited-part-1)

There already exist modules in the MS powershellgallery.com that do this menu thing for you.

> [powershellgallery 'console menu'](https://www.bing.com/search?q=powershellgallery%20%27console%20menu%27&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=powershellgallery%20%27console%20menu%27&sc=0-32&sk=&cvid=56BECA9C71FA49B59CE947F6038B4529)

Youtube again for menu creation...

> [PowerShell menus](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershell%20menus)

Modules you can download and use for such menu thing, are in your PowerShell session.

```
Find-Module -Name '*menu*' | 
Format-Table -AutoSize

<#
# Results

Version  Name                     Repository Description                                                                                                                           
-------  ----                     ---------- -----------                                                                                                                           
1.0.6    ps-menu                  PSGallery  Powershell module to generate interactive console menu                                                                                
0.2      MenuShell                PSGallery  Make console menus in seconds with MenuShell                                                                                          
1.0.52.0 CliMenu                  PSGallery  Easily build and edit CLI menus in Powershell                                                                                         
0.1.1    ServerOpsMenu            PSGallery  PowerShell module to provide maintenance menu for Windows servers                                                                     
1.0.1    PSScriptMenuGui          PSGallery  Use a CSV file to make a graphical menu of PowerShell scripts. Easy to customise and fast to launch....                               
1.0.0.0  SimpleMenu               PSGallery  Create and invoke a simple menu interface.                                                                                            
2.21     DosInstallUtilities.Menu PSGallery  Functions to create menus                                                                                                             
1.0.2001 SS.CliMenu               PSGallery  CLI menu infrastructure for PowerShell. ...                                                                                           
1.0.0.2  MenuSelect               PSGallery  Module description                                                                                                                    
1.0.4    SLMenu                   PSGallery  Text User Interface Module for Powershell Console                                                                                     
0.1.1    PSMenu                   PSGallery  Powershell module to generate interactive console menu....                                                                            
0.5      ContextSensitiveMenus    PSGallery  Allows you to add type-sensitive context menus to WPF controls                                                                        

#>
```

As well as threads on the topic Stackoverflow.

The real question is why a console menu when you can use the PowerShell GUI tools to do this? Just pull a list of VM's using the PowerShell / Hyper-V/VMWare cmdlets, shunt those or Out-GridView for users to select from. That is literally a one-line script.

```
# Show the default Out-GridView as a user menu
Get-VM -Name '*' | 
Sort-Object -Property Name | 
Out-GridView -Title 'Select one or more Windows host to use. CRTL+LeftMouseClick to select more than one' -Passthru | 
Start-VM -ComputerName $PSItem
```

Not much other code needed if all you are doing is presenting a list of VM's for a user to select to start up. No need for external files.

For that MDI approach, you seem to be after. You can still use Out-GridView for that. [See the examples here](https://www.bing.com/search?q=out-gridview%20as%20a%20gui&form=ANNTH1&refig=9d7a75f64da54f2184d9df303c9de659&sp=-1&pq=out-gridview%20as%20a%20gui&sc=0-21&qs=n&sk=&cvid=9d7a75f64da54f2184d9df303c9de659):

> [Creating a Simplistic GUI Interface with Out-GridView](https://mikefrobbins.com/2014/09/11/creating-a-simplistic-gui-interface-with-out-gridview/)

If you want to get even more elegant, you could even use the built-in PowerShell help option or write your own Windows form. For Example of a simple GUI tool for VM selection with dynamics list population using dynamic parameters, for power on/off.

```
function Get-UserVM 
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    [Alias('guvm')]  

    param
    (
        [ValidateSet('On', 'Off')]
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string]$State        
    )

    DynamicParam 
    {
        # Set the dynamic parameters' name
        $ParameterName = 'VMName'

        # Create the dictionary 
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameterDictionary

        # Create the collection of attributes
        $AttributeCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[System.Attribute]

        # Create and set the parameters' attributes
        $ParameterAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ParameterAttribute
        $ParameterAttribute.Mandatory = $true
        $ParameterAttribute.Position = 1

        # Add the attributes to the attributes collection
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ParameterAttribute)

        # Generate and set the ValidateSet 
        $arrSet = ((Get-VM).Name)
        $ValidateSetAttribute = New-Object System.Management.Automation.ValidateSetAttribute($arrSet)

        # Add the ValidateSet to the attributes collection
        $AttributeCollection.Add($ValidateSetAttribute)

        # Create and return the dynamic parameter
        $RuntimeParameter = New-Object System.Management.Automation.RuntimeDefinedParameter($ParameterName, [string], $AttributeCollection)
        $RuntimeParameterDictionary.Add($ParameterName, $RuntimeParameter)
        return $RuntimeParameterDictionary
    }



    begin 
    {
        # Bind the parameter to a friendly variable
        $Script:VNName = $PsBoundParameters[$ParameterName]
    }

    process 
    {
        switch ($State) 
        { 
            On
            {
                "Attempting to start $Script:VNName"
                Start-VM -Name $Script:VNName
            } 
            Off
            {
                "Attempting to stop $Script:VNName"
                Stop-VM -Name $Script:VNName
            } 
            default {Write-Warning -Message "$Script:VNName state could not be determined"}
        }    
    }
}

Show-Command -Name Get-UserVM

# Or
Show-Command -Name guvm

# Or 
shcm guvm
```

Yet, it's your choice. Yet, as I show, you have many options, and the only way to know if you've chosen the right one is to learn about them first.